# Xcode 11.3 beta how to navigate to top in UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11

While switching tabs, I need to navigate to the top of tableview.

```swift
func scrollToFirstRow() {
      if let rowCount = self.dataSource?.tableView(self,numberOfRowsInSection: 0), rowCount > 0 {
          let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
          self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
          self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 10), animated: true)
      }
  }
```

With Xcode 10.1 and iOS11 I am navigating to top while switching tabs using above code.

But `tableview` not scrolling to top with iOS 13 and Xcode 11.3 Beta

Answer (score 0):

assign the indexPath value as row 0 and section 0. This is working well for me in iOS 13

```
    self.chatTable.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

**UPDATE**:

You need to call it once the tableview has finished loading. Here is how you can check the end of loading:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let lastVisibleIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last {
            if indexPath == lastVisibleIndexPath {
                // call your scrollToFirstRow function here 
            }
        }
    }
```

Also in your viewWillAppear, just call tableView.reloadData()

Comment: create a breakpoint and check if the code is being executed or not.

Comment: @ Keshu Rai Code is executing

Comment: if using tabbar, Use this method in viewWillAppear

Comment: when are you calling this method? I think you are calling it before your table view has finished loading all data.

Comment: @Awasis I am calling this method in ViewWillAppear

Comment: @Keshu Rai The same code working on iOS11 and below

Answer (score 0):

Just call this method:

`self.chatTable.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated:true)`

or

`self.chatTable.setContentOffset(.zero, animated:true)`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by calling scrollToFirstRow() on DispatchQueue